# Simple Java networking game engine

Tags: java, networking

I want to create a simple java networking game and search a networking engine that eases use of sockets etc. I have already read some questions on here and the internet about java networking for games, but many of them were over 10 years old or not really answered.

I have no idea whatsoever about what exactly I need to send in terms of messages, but I figured simple strings or integers will be enough for my purposes.

It's basically a peer to peer game, so I don't need a centralized server structure. Messaging doesn't have to have an extremely low ping, yet of course all players need to have a synchronized view.

What are the possibilities I have here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will probably want to build something that is based on the [Netty IO library](http://netty.io/). Netty is a very good IO library suitable for high performance / low latency communications of the type you need in games.

You could use Netty directly, but it might also make sense to use a higher level library that has been specifically designed for games. I found this on Github, might be just what you need:

- https://github.com/menacher/java-game-server

Alternatively, if you are using a Java game engine like [jMonkeyEngine](http://jmonkeyengine.com/) then this may already contain the networking features that you need:

- http://jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jme3:advanced:networking

Comment: I checked into both and I think Netty is very good for my needs. I don't use a Game Engine yet, because I really want to learn things and not use too high level engines. Will look into game server also. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was reviewing this article today:

- [Ultra fast reliable messaging](http://java.dzone.com/articles/ultra-fast-reliable-messaging)

For another endeavour (not a game).  Fast messaging libraries offer another alternative, especially those for high volume small messages (e.g. twitter, ForEx, Airlines, etc).